# Asynchronous Client Server Communication Issue

Tags: c#, asynchronous, client-server

I am new to programming and I am working on an asynchronous client server application.
I can send a message to the server from the client, but when I receive the data to the server (OnDataReceived Method) and try to send the same data back to the client (for testing purposes) I can't.
Not sure what other info I need to give, so please let me know, I don't mean to be vague.

SERVER CODE

```
public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        try
        {
            SocketPacket socketData = (SocketPacket)asyncResult.AsyncState;
            int iRx = 0;
            iRx = socketData.currentSocket.EndReceive(asyncResult);
            char[] chars = new char[iRx];
            Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            int charLen = decoder.GetChars(socketData.dataBuffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
            String receivedData = new String(chars);

            //BroadCast(receivedData);

            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => lbxMessages.Items.Add(receivedData)));

            //Updated Code
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => broadcast(receivedData)));

            WaitForData(socketData.currentSocket);


        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\n OnDataRecieved: Socket has been closed\n");
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }
    }

public class SocketPacket
    {
        public Socket currentSocket;
        public byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[50];//allowing the 50 digist to be sent at once
    }

    private void WaitForData(Socket socket)
    {
        try
        {
            if (workerCallBack == null)
            {
                workerCallBack = OnDataReceived;
            }
            SocketPacket sckPack = new SocketPacket();
            sckPack.currentSocket = socket;
            socket.BeginReceive(sckPack.dataBuffer, 0, sckPack.dataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, workerCallBack, sckPack);
        }
        catch(SocketException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }
    }
```

Updated in response to Andrew's reply

I have a method that will be invoked when a client is connected

```
private void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        try
        {
            //Here we complete/end the Beginaccept() asynchronous call by
            //calling EndAccept() - which returns the reference to a new socket object
            workerSocket[clientCount] = listenSocket.EndAccept(asyncResult);

            //Let the worker socket do the further processing for the just connected client
            WaitForData(workerSocket[clientCount]);

            //Now increment the client count
            ++clientCount;

            if (clientCount<4)//allow max 3 clients
            {
                //Adds the connected client to the list
                connectedClients.Add(listenSocket);
                String str = String.Format("Client # {0} connected", clientCount);                   

                this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    //Display this client connection as a status message on the GUI
                    lbxMessages.Items.Add(str);
                    lblConnectionStatus.Content =clientCount + " Connected";
                }));

                //Since the main Socket is now free, it can go back and wait for
                //other clients who are attempting to connect
                listenSocket.BeginAccept(OnClientConnect, null);
            }
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\n OnClientConnection: Socket has been closed\n");
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            HandleClientDisconnect(listenSocket);
        }
    }
```

(UPDATED)
ADDED METHOD TO BROADCAST MESSAGE RECEIVED BY SERVER BACK TO CLIENT

```
public void broadcast(string msg)
    {
        //foreach (Socket item in connectedClients)
        //{
        Socket broadcastSocket;
        broadcastSocket = workerSocket[0]; //sends message to first client connected
        byte[] broadcastBytes = null;
        broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
        broadcastSocket.Send(broadcastBytes);
        //}
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by you can't send data back to the client? What error do you receive?
BTW if you new to programming start from synchronous version first and only then move to asynchronous.

Comment: The error read 'A request to send or received data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied'

Comment: Reading your update, I believe you should be writing to the socket you're keeping in workerSocket[ClientCount]. On Clientcount, not related to your question but you may want to debug how you're using this - you appear to be writing data to an array - workerSocket[ClientCount]; then you're later incrementing, and then maybe/maybe not doing work with it. Seems to me that the 4th client will be added to WorkerSocket; also have a WaitForData issued, but then not added to connectedClient etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is two sockets involved in server-side TCP communication. First socket is a listening socket and you should use it only for accepting new request. Then every time you accept new request from the client you're getting another socket for every connection.

You trying to send data back via **listening socket** but not via socket that you accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Sergey has it right. If you're looking to have one server handle multiple clients, then you'll need some sort of ServerTerminal class which can listen for new connections and then setup some sort of "connectedclient" class to handle IO to that socket. Your "OnDataReceived" method would be in the connectedclient class.

In your socket accept routine it should look something like:

```
private void OnClientConnection(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        if (socketClosed)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            Socket clientSocket = listenSocket.EndAccept(asyn);

            ConnectedClient connectedClient = new ConnectedClient(clientSocket, this, _ServerTerminalReceiveMode);

            connectedClient.StartListening();
```

In the accept routine you're passed a socket - i've named this "clientSocket". This is the socket you want to write to, not the listening socket.

Comment: I have a method to deal with clients connecting if thats what your talking about.